# Materializecss tooltip not working with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tooltip, materialize, web-frontend

I recently started learning `Angularjs` and I'm stuck when implementing `materializecss` `tooltip` with angular scope.

**HTML**

```
<div class="color-picker">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="color in colors">
        <div class="color tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="color.colorName" ng-style="{'background-color': color.hexValue}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is color data:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.colors = 
[
    {
        colorName: "red",
        hexValue: "#f00"
    },
    {
        colorName: "green",
        hexValue: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        colorName: "blue",
        hexValue: "#00f"
    },
    {
        colorName: "cyan",
        hexValue: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        colorName: "magenta",
        hexValue: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        colorName: "yellow",
        hexValue: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        colorName: "black",
        hexValue: "#000"
    },
    {
        colorName: "white",
        hexValue: "#fff"
    }
]
}]);
```

I've successfully show different colors, but failed to show colorName with `tooltip` and I don't want to use extra plugin like `angular-materialize` if possible. Thanks guys.

**EDIT**

Sorry, here is my **js** files:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/main-controller.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you linked `jquery` and `materialize.js` files?

Comment: @TirthPatel seems so, i wonder if i should place materialize.js below angular.js

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that ng-repeat edit the html code and that breaks the tooltip functionality, you must create an angular directive (as far as I know). I can't give you a piece of code to solve that because I'm using [angular-materialize](https://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/). I had the same problem and I solved it with the `tooltipped` directive of angular-materialize ([tooltipped directive](https://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#tooltip)).

I know you said you don't want to use something like angular-materialize but that's how I solved the problem. I suppose you can look the code of that plugin to make your own directive.

Sorry I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the [Angular-materialize](https://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize) plugin, it's has directives you can use when making use of angular and materializecss. You can check the documentation for the tooltip [here](https://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#tooltip) and don't forget to inject `ui.materialize` like so:

`var app = angular.module('tooltipApp', ['ui.materialize'])`

Comment: I used ui.materialize , now it showing the tooltip , but it shown at the top corner of the screen insted of  near the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using the angular-materialize plugin. Try this in your controller:

```
$('.color-picker').tooltip().tooltip('show');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({ delay: 50 });
});
```